# Split record data in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hi all can you please assist me,

I would like to split my records into different year and month see below I want figure one to be split into different categories but this must all display on one page.

my current result set is like this:

```
Date Year   Date Month  Instructor  Num Of Members
2013            November    Jones       57
2013            November    Smith       40
2013            November    Moreleta    55
2013            November    James       65
2013            November    Soodie      65
2014            January     Jones       47
2014            January     Smith       55
2014            January     Moreleta    60
2014            January     James       73
2014            January     Soodie      68
2014            February    Jones       48
2014            February    Smith       60
2014            February    Moreleta    66
2014            February    James       75
2014            February    Soodie      68
```

I want them to be split like the one below. Can any of you assist me in doing this.

```
Date Year   Date Month  Instructor  Num Of Members
2013            November    Jones       57
2013            November    Smith       40
2013            November    Moreleta    55
2013            November    James       65
2013            November    Soodie      65

2014            January     Jones       47
2014            January     Smith       55
2014            January     Moreleta    60
2014            January     James       73
2014            January     Soodie      68

2014            February    Jones       48
2014            February    Smith       60
2014            February    Moreleta    66
2014            February    James       75
2014            February    Soodie      68
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have 3 grids all with the same data source and a filter on the year and month. This would be a static filter though so you would be better off having 1 grid that step grouped on year and month.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx) shows you everything you need to know in order to do it in one grid.